# How to make this awk script less boilerplate?

Tags: awk, refactoring

Suppose I've got a log file like this (1st column is a timestamp):

```
1699740442177 Start A
1699740442177 Start B
1699740442255 Start C
1699740442261 Finish B
1699740442337 Finish C
1699740442337 Finish A
```

I want to determine how much time in average it took for `A`, `B`, and `C`.  So I wrote an `awk` script :

```
/Start A/ {
  startA = $1
}
/Finish A/ {
  sumA += $1 - startA
  numA++ 
}
/Start B/ {
  startB = $1
}
/Finish B/ {
  sumB += $1 - startB
  numB++ 
}
/Start C/ {
  startC = $1
}
/Finish C/ {
  sumC += $1 - startC
  numC++ 
}
END {
  print sumA/numA, sumB/numB, sumC/numC
}
```

The script works but it is somewhat *boilerplate*. How would you suggest improve the script and make it less boilerplate ?

The number of letters may vary (10-15 letters max). We can assume there is no overlap between `Start/Finish` pairs for the same letter.

Comment: please update the question with the expected output (corresponding to the provided sample inputs)

Comment: the inclusion of `numX++`, and final division by `numX`, seems to imply you could have multiple `Start/Finish` blocks for a given letter; are there guaranteed to be *no* overlaps between `Start/Finish` pairs (for a given letter, eg, `A`)? please update the question to show an example of 2 `Start/Finish` pairs for a letter

Comment: will there always be 3 letters (eg, `A`, `B`, `C`) or could the number of letters vary? what is the expected max number of unique letters? assuming there could be a variable number of letters, is there a requirement to *a)* print the results in a given order and/or *b)* label the outputs (eg, `"A =",sumA/numA`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks for the suggestions. Updated the question.

Comment: Are the keys always guaranteed to run nested uniquely like that and you could never have, say, `Start A; Start B; Finish A; Finish B`? Can you ever have a Start without a Finish or vice-versa and, if so, how should that be handled?

Comment: The keys are _not_ necessarily nested (see `B` and `C` in my example). A Start without a Finish and visa versa should be ignored.

Comment: @Michael what does "should be ignored" mean - that we should ignore that possibility when writing our code or that if such a possibility occurs in your data the mismatched Start or Finish should just be discarded without any notification being printed to stderr or something else?

Comment: Can you ever have `Start A; Start A; ... Finish A; Finish A`? If so, does it mean the 2 ranges are nested (first Start A goes with second Finish A) or overlapping (first Start A goes with first Finish A) or should the first Start A be discarded when followed by a second Start A before the first Finish A (and then the second Finish A discarded) or something else?

Comment: Mismatched Start or Finish should be discarded. We can assume that `Start A; Start A; ... Finish A; Finish A` does not happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store starting timestamps, absolute sums, and counts into arrays, all indexed by the third column, and print out the averages at the `END`:

```bash
$2 == "Start"  { t[$3] = $1; n[$3] += 1 }
$2 == "Finish" { s[$3] += $1 - t[$3] }
END { for (k in n) print "Average of", k, "is", s[k] / n[k] }
```

```
Average of A is 160
Average of B is 84
Average of C is 82
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions/understandings:

- number of identifiers (single letters in example data) could vary
- there could be multiple `Start/Finish` pairs
- multiple `Start/Finish` pairs (for a given identifier) do not overlap
- order of output (identifiers) does not matter
- all values are to be printed on one line (we'll add the identifier in parens after each average)

Adding a few data lines:

```
$ cat ts.dat
1699740442177 Start A
1699740442177 Start B
1699740442255 Start C
1699740442261 Finish B
1699740442337 Finish C
1699740442337 Finish A
1699740490000 Start C
1699740493500 Start DEF
1699740494000 Finish C
1699740496500 Finish DEF
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/Start/  { start[$3] = $1 }
/Finish/ { sum[$3]  += ($1 - start[$3])
           num[$3]++
         }
END      { sep=""
           for (i in sum) {
               printf "%s%0.2f(%s)", sep, sum[i]/num[i], i
               sep = OFS
           }
           print ""

           #### following is for debug purposes and can be removed/commented-out once code is validated
           print "########## sums/nums"
           for (i in sum)
               print i, sum[i] "/" num[i], (num[i] ? sum[i]/num[i] : 0)
         }
' ts.dat
```

This generates:

```
160.00(A) 84.00(B) 2041.00(C) 3000.00(DEF)
########## sums/nums
A 160/1 160
B 84/1 84
C 4082/2 2041
DEF 3000/1 3000
```

**NOTE:** while this output is in fact ordered by identifier this isn't guaranteed; ordering could be guaranteed with a bit more code (and depending on version of `awk`)

Answer (score 2):

This, using GNU awk for arrays of arrays, may (or may not!) handle overlapping ranges, and/or missing values in your input correctly depending on what your requirements are for those:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    time=$1; type=$2; key=$3
    cnt = ++cnts[key][type]
    times[key][type][cnt] = time
}
END {
    for ( key in times ) {
        sum = 0
        for ( cnt in times[key]["Finish"] ) {
            if ( cnt in times[key]["Start"] ) {
                sum += times[key]["Finish"][cnt] - times[key]["Start"][cnt]
            }
        }
        ave = ( cnt ? sum / cnt : 0 )
        printf "Key=%s, cnt=%d, sum=%d, ave=%0.2f\n", key, cnt, sum, ave
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Key=A, cnt=1, sum=160, ave=160.00
Key=B, cnt=1, sum=84, ave=84.00
Key=C, cnt=1, sum=82, ave=82.00
```

The provided sample input doesn't cover any of the rainy-day cases and there's no provided expected output so it obviously hasn't been tested for those cases.